# Secure password by keyring Python?

Tags: python

I know keyring save user,password at **Windows Credentials**. But user can change it and it is very dangerous. So how can I dishable user change it?
(I'm in windows 10)

Comment: This is a really good question by itself, but I don't think Python can do that, since it requires permissioons that a `.bat` file would do. I suggest this approach: use a `.bat` file to run a Python script which contains input listeners and the logic of your code. See how [the login system interferes this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm#:~:text=If%20there%20are%20two%20or,Windows%208%20and%2010.).

Comment: Also, I think you can [edit] the question to specify which version of Windows you're targeting (for eg: Windows 10), as these features may vary, and by "Windows Credentials", do you mean [this section in the Settings or Control Panel](https://ibb.co/8Bs3TgQ)?

Comment: See this: https://superuser.com/questions/790559/how-to-run-a-batch-file-at-windows-login and this thread too: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2036059-batch-script-to-add-windows-credentials-windows-7.